# user token doesn't work with sonarqube6.4 api?

Tags: python-3.x, api, curl, sonarqube, token

I'm trying to write a python code to get the metric's values of project on sonarqube 6.4. However I can't get resultuts with user token:

```
curl -u THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN: https://sonarqube.com/api/user_tokens/search
# note that the colon after the token is required in curl to set an empty password
```

Maybe I'm using the token in a wrong way. I write it in python directly with os.system. And then when I try request.get('https://sonarqube.XXXX.com/api/measures/component?XXXX'), it doesn't work. It shows response.status_code=401.

Can someone help me to figure out the problem?

Thanks

Comment: First update to a LTS version and check if the problem still exists.

Comment: It's our company using sonarqube and I can't update it. I just need to write a python to get information from the web page of sonarqube. But I can't be authorized with my token.

Comment: I make a mistake. It's already Sonarqube 6.7. But it doesn't work.